# appendChild method is not defined when using with a div element

Tags: javascript, dom, append

I'm really a beginner in Javascript and trying to add a `p` element inside a `div` element in this HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
        <p>This is paragraph 2.</p>
        <p>This is paragraph 3.</p>
        <p>This is paragraph 4.</p>
        <div>
            <p id="foo">This is paragraph 5.</p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

using this code :

```
(function(){
    var divElement = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        el = document.createElement("p");
        content = document.createTextNode("This is text");    
    el.appendChild(content);
    document.divElement.appendChild(el);        
}());
```

But i get this error at line 6 :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName(" ... ")` returns a collection of elements.

```
var divElement = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
```

Also, change:

```
document.divElement.appendChild(el);
```

To:

```
divElement.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: @Rafael [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)

Comment: Ya, that did it. Thank you and Andreas :) But may i ask what's the difference between `document.divElement.appentChile(el)`, `document.body.divElement.appendChild(el)` and `divElement.appendChild(el)` ?

Comment: `divElement`, when assigned to `document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]`, essentially already includes the `document.body` portion since it's pointing to that specific div under the document object. Using "document.divElement.appendChild(el)" would be equivalent to repeating the `document` portion twice (document.document.body), which is incorrect and why it fails.

Comment: Much more easy with jQuery: `$("div").append($("<p>").html("This is paragraph 5.").attr("id","foo"));` Done.

Answer (score 1):

One of your variable names is a bit misleading, namely `divElement`. Since you are using `getElementsByTagName()` (notice `elements`), it will return a list of elements, not a single one. Therefore, you should name the variable `divElements` to make it less confusing.

I've modified your code to work with a list of elements instead:

```
(function() {
    var divElements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var el = document.createElement("p");
    var content = document.createTextNode("This is text");

    el.appendChild(content);

    for (var i = 0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
        divElements[i].appendChild(el);
    }
}());​
```

And a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UmKYq/5/

Answer (score -1):

```
var div =  document.createElement("div");

document.lastChild.appendChild(div);

var a=[];

var n=[];



var txt=["Lovey", "komal", "Sona", "Purvi", "Sanchi"];

for (i=0; i<=txt.length; i++)

{
    a[i]=document.createElement("a");

    a[i].setAttribute("href","#");

    n[i].appendChild(n[i]);

    div.appendChild(n[i]);

    div.appendChild(a[i]);   

}
```